# Storage efficient remote file integrity check for embedded Linux device

Tags: linux

I have embedded Linux device with limited RAM and Flash.
Due to limited RAM and Flash, I need to download the binary file from HTTP server in small chunks and then write that chunk to the flash. 
Problem is, I can't determine the integrity of the file until I download a last chunk. In worst case, after getting a last chunk of the file, I might find that file is tampered or it is not 'integral' as expected (I have expected md5sum of that file), but then I have already download in chunks and written to the flash.(I can mark flash downloaded area as valid after the last chunk, but I have already wasted time and flash-life by that time)
Is there any way to send a request to remote HTTP server to verify say md5sum of the file against the expected md5sum value?

Comment: Do you control the remote server?  I mean, you could request / make it send an intermediate checksum for every MB prior to sending the file.  How do you obtain the checksum of the whole file?

Comment: I don't have control of remote server. 'Actual checksum' (not the 'expected checksum') of 1 MB memory chunk can't be requested from HTTP server; there is no HTTP command to do so.              Checksum for every MB will ensure integrity of that 1 MB only. I need to check integrity of entire file. Someone can hack the HTTP server and altered the small portion of the binary file.

Comment: *“Checksum for every MB will ensure integrity of that 1 MB only”* – You can do better by using a running checksum: use a single hashing context, feed it all of the stream (function usually called `update`) and request the *current* (covering byte 0 to current) checksum (function usually called `digest`) whenever you feel like so.  The intermediate checksums are a bonus that you get mostly for free, since you are computing the total checksum anyway.  However, if you have no chance of asking the server for those checksums, I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: "if you have no chance of asking the server for those checksums, I'm afraid you're out of luck"                                          For some installations I may have access to to HTTP sever. Say if I have access then how it can be done using HTTP/Etags may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand about your problem from the discussion in the comments, this is the high-level picture *assuming you can add stuff to the server*.

**On the client side:**

- Request the list of running checksums (*c*<sub>*i*</sub>)<sub>*i*=1,…,n</sub> for file *F* in chunks of *m* bytes from the server.
- Create a hash context *C*.
- Request the file *F* from the server.
- Repeat for every *m* byte chunk (*b*<sub>*i*</sub>)<sub>*i*=1,…,n</sub> received:

  - Update the hash context: update(*C*, *b*<sub>*i*</sub>)
  - Compute the current digest: *d*<sub>*i*</sub> ← digest(*C*, *b*<sub>*i*</sub>)
  - If *d*<sub>*i*</sub> ≠ *c*<sub>*i*</sub>:

    - Abort the transfer, report an error, try again, whatever…
  - Save chunk *b*<sub>*i*</sub> to disk.

**On the server side:**

- If a client requests the list of running checksums (*c*<sub>*i*</sub>)<sub>*i*=1,…,n</sub> for file *F* in chunks of *m* bytes:

  - Create a hash context *C*.
  - Repeat for every *m* byte chunk (*b*<sub>*i*</sub>)<sub>*i*=1,…,n</sub> of *F*:

    - Update the hash context: update(*C*, *b*<sub>*i*</sub>)
    - Compute the current digest: *d*<sub>*i*</sub> ← digest(*C*, *b*<sub>*i*</sub>)
    - Send *d*<sub>*i*</sub> to the client.
- Else if a client requests file *F*:

  - Send *F* to the client.

This scheme lets you request the list of running checksums (maybe just a text file with one digest per line) in chunks for file `file.dat` of 1 Mib via a normal HTTP request like `http://example.com/checksums?algorithm=md5;file=file.dat;chunksize=1048576`.  The actual file data can later be requested like `http://example.com/file.dat`.

Alternatively – if you think that most clients will want the checksums but don't need fine-grained control over the algorithm or chunk size – you could add additional HTTP headers and make your server's reply look like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 52428800
My-Checksum-Algorithm: md5
My-Checksum-Chunk-Size: 1048576
My-Checksum-Chunk: chunk=0, digest=c9a3a83280571697868f12e74e4ede4f
My-Checksum-Chunk: chunk=1, digest=d0c13dff943c5b67f411732304b6f46f
My-Checksum-Chunk: chunk=2, digest=34465c3e2e2eb2576d46253bea5cfc44
My-Checksum-Chunk: ...
My-Checksum-Total: f2bf55ff8b38dc667b91b6b988cdf940

Here goes the data...
```

It should not be hard for you to parse the headers to extract the required information.  Of course, the format of the headers will need to be adapted to your specific needs.

If you are using [*chunked transfer encoding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), you might want to add the checksums along with each chunk, not all at the beginning so to save the server process the file twice.

Note that all of the above can only help detect accidental data corruption. (Which is something that TCP already tries to make unlikely so I'm not sure how much you will gain by being overly pessimistic.)  What this scheme cannot do is protect against man-in-the-middle attacks.  If this is what concerns you, you should establish a trusted TLS connection (HTTPS) and only then transfer the file.  But even HTTPS cannot protect you if someone breaks into the server.  If this is a possibility that should be handled as well, you could sign the data with OpenPGP and verify the integrity of the signature.  Of course, the private key used to create the signature must then not be stored on the server.

Comment: Thank you Moritz for detailed answer. Let me digest it as i am new in HTTP area!

Comment: You said, request the list of running check-sums by HTTP request like                                                        "http://example.com/checksums?algorithm=md5;file=file.dat;chunksize=1048576"                                                  I didn't quite get this. Is this a standard HTTP request format? How to do it via curl-API? What needs to be changed on HTTP server? Just the contents or install some HTTP extensions?

Comment: It is “standard HTTP” in the sense that it is allowed by the standard but it won't work automagically for you.  You'll need to put a PHP script `checksums` or whatever at the server that parses the request URL and generates and sends the checksums as described above.  It is not difficult (corner cases aside, I guess you can do it in less than 100 lines of PHP), but you'll have to do it nonetheless.